# How to get rid of diacriticial marks (~ from ñ, ' from á and é)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert diacritical characters (ñ, á, é, ...) to plain characters . I would prefer a simple regexp solution (as in: an oneliner) in JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: You want to do the conversion in PHP or js???

Comment: "café" is an acceptable spelling, in English, according to the OED. So "é" is not a "non-English character".

Comment: The proper terminology is "diacritical characters", not "non-English characters". See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic. I fixed the question for you.

Comment: @Balanivash i did mention js in the title & post

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the correct terminology

Comment: ya, but got a lil confused on reading the question, cos in the first line you have mentioned that you wish to convert in php.

Comment: @Web Developer: You still need to clarify if you want to do it in PHP or JS or jQuery. You tagged JS/jQuery, but you mentioned PHP in the question.

Comment: @Web Developer, You said "I want to convert ... in PHP"

Comment: Note that the translation table might differ depending on the language of the text. For example, in German, "ä" is replaced by "ae", but that might not be true for Nordic languages using "ä".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a javascript solution

http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in php like this:

```
$normalized = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

For example, it will convert `ñáé` to `nae`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks for the solution but i am looking for a js solution anyways thanks for the tip